# Logging calls on the iPad

Tags: salesforce1-app, ipad

The Salesforce1 app allows users to log calls on iPhone and Android devices. However we have a client that wants to log them using an iPad. The documentation does not seem to indicate any reason the publisher action to Log a call would be hidden from the iPad but would appear on the iPhone.

1. Is this a config issue? We've searched high and low for why the log a call icon would appear on the iPhone but no the iPad without any luck.
2. If (1) is false. Can the iPad log calls without a custom implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The log a call publisher action should appear on iPad. There isn't anything that is device specific that would be controlling it that I'm aware of. Here it is on my iPad:
[image: Here it is on my iPad]

Just the same as on my iPhone:
[image: Just the same as on my iPhone]

However, the publisher actions are contextual, meaning if you are viewing a record that doesn't support that particular action, you won't see it. So if, for example, you are looking at a user profile in Salesforce 1, you will not see the log a call action because there is no activity related list on the User object:
[image: No log a call action]

So be sure that you are viewing either the general feed, or an object that can have related activities to see that action.

Comment: I talked to my BA on this case, they said it's a contact record and it shows up just fine on the iphone but not the ipad.

Comment: Just brainstorming... 
- Has the user swiped the publisher to the second panel of actions? There could be more than one.
- Is the user certain they are logged in as the same user in both devices?
- If the user navigates to the feed (top-most menu item in left-side menu) and opens publisher on both devices, do they still see different actions?

Answer (score 0):

With my research via I have determined that You need to have a Cellular enabled iPad for the Log a call function to be available. A Wi-Fi enabled will not have the option.